# How to access original event object when d3 event binding

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In d3, I have bound the mousedown event on a node to a function I want to execute:

```
let node = gA.svg.selectAll('.node').data(gA.force.nodes(), gA.node_id)
let node_group = node.enter().append('g')
    .classed('node', true)
    .call(gA.drag)

node_group.append('circle')
    .classed('node-circle', true)
    // we may consider adding the position too. it will get updated on the 
    // next tick anyway, so we will only add it here if things look glitchy
    .attr('r', gA.node_radius) 
    .on(gA.circle_events)
    .on('mousedown', mousedown)
    .on('mouseup', mouseup)
```

Only the last line is truly relevant here.  That and the fact I'm using d3.

But now when I define my mouseup function...

```
function mouseup(datum, something1, something2) {
    alert("But where is the Event object?  :(  :'(  ")
}
```

datum is the datum bound to the svg 'circle'.  something1 appears to be the x-position of the mouse relative to the element (my best guess).  And something2 appears to be the y-position.

But how do I access the Event?  I needed to access Event.clientX.

Comment: One way I might be able to do it.  If I could access the svg circle itself, I could look for its "top" and "left" attributes to get its position.  But I don't know how to access that either.  Only datum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [well documented](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_event):

> d3.event
>
> Stores the current event, if any. This global is registered during an event listener callback with the on operator. The current event is reset after the listener is notified in a finally block. This allows the listener function to have the same form as other operator functions, being passed the current datum d and index i.

Comment: Thanks Lars!  Wish I had found that myself.